# How use ROW_NUMBER() in Room @Query?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

Problem :

I am hitting a `api` in my application which send's date in pages(page size = 20).So currently i am trying to save data in my local db using `ROOM` which is a basic insert operation.And when the application is not connected to network i want the app to get data from db in form of pages.

Solution(what i have tried):

Inside `DAO` layer i using

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( ORDER BY rating ) RowNum,* FROM movie ) t WHERE t.RowNum > 0 AND t.RowNum <= 20")
 suspend fun getPagedMovie(): List<MovieEntity>
```

i am getting two compilation error:

> < compound operator >, FROM, GROUP, LIMIT, ORDER, WHERE or comma expected,

&

> cannot relove t.RowNum

So, as to solve this i tried use @RawQuery

```
val query = SimpleSQLiteQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( ORDER BY rating ) RowNum,* FROM movie ) t WHERE t.RowNum > 0 AND t.RowNum <= 20"
    )
return movieDao.getPagedMovie(query).map { it.toGeneralMovie() }
```

&

```
 @RawQuery
 suspend fun getPagedMovie(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): List<MovieEntity>
```

In above case i am getting below in error log:

> 2020-04-18 16:23:33.014 21854-21854/? E/m.andor.watchi: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
>   2020-04-18 16:23:34.158 21854-21891/com.andor.watchit E/[Gralloc-ERROR]: sanitize_formats:482 Format [id:0x4] which doesn't support afbc should not have bpp defined
>   2020-04-18 16:23:34.415 21854-21979/com.andor.watchit E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "(": syntax error
>   2020-04-18 16:23:34.456 21854-21978/com.andor.watchit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-3
>       Process: com.andor.watchit, PID: 21854
>       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( ORDER BY rating ) RowNum,* FROM movie ) t WHERE t.RowNum > 0 AND t.RowNum <= 20
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1372)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:811)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:62)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1959)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1934)
>           at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.query(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:161)
>           at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:328)
>           at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(DBUtil.java:83)
>           at com.andor.watchit.core.framework.db.MovieDao_Impl$8.call(MovieDao_Impl.java:237)
>           at com.andor.watchit.core.framework.db.MovieDao_Impl$8.call(MovieDao_Impl.java:234)
>           at androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom$Companion$execute$2.invokeSuspend(CoroutinesRoom.kt:54)
>           at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
>           at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

I would like to know a solution to implement pagination using ROOM ?

P.S. : my query is just to fetch 1st 20 element's right now i.e 1st page i can make it dynamic query later on and on DB Browser it work.On side note I don't want to load the whole result and then make pages.

Comment: can you use skip and take mechanism like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13221574/2514250

Comment: Thanks for the above i did found the solution of LIMIT and OFFSET and used as solution was gng to post here @dev-masih

Comment: But still if i can get solution with row_number it will be great.Current Solution is correct but i think row_number solution also interest me.

Comment: i added a solution with ROW_NUMBER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the solution to above problem by using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM movie ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT :pageSize OFFSET (:pageNumber-1)*:pageSize")
suspend fun getPagedMovie(pageNumber: Int, pageSize: Int): List<MovieEntity>
```

Wish this help's other people also.

And thanks to @dev-masih also for giving a reference in comment's.

Comment: Great .. for more info about LIMIT & OFFSET. you can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61200289/how-to-get-the-first-or-any-element-from-a-livedata-list-in-android-mvvm-archi/61215051#61215051)