# How to get last value from Room using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-viewmodel

How should i return only one value from Room?

I've made my query in the DAO like:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM testata WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM testata)")
fun selectLast(): Testata
```

Which should return the last insert row, then in my repository i've done the following:

```
@WorkerThread
suspend fun lastTestata(): Testata {
    return testataDAO.selectLast()
}
```

And in the ViewModal i was trying the following:

```
fun lastTestata(): Testata = viewModelScope.launch {
    return repository.lastTestata()
}
```

But instead it requires Job instead of testata in ViewModal `fun lastTestata()` so what is the right way to get single values from room in android?

Comment: @a_local_nobody i need the whole object as prefil some field with the last row in the db

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get the first or (any) element from a LiveData List in Android MVVM architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61200289/how-to-get-the-first-or-any-element-from-a-livedata-list-in-android-mvvm-archi)

Comment: @Serhat it doesn't as i'm using suspend and viewModelScope.launch in repository and ViewModel

Answer (score 2):

If your id is incremental(should be) you can use the limit to get one register, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM testata ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The query "SELECT * FROM testata WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM testata)" will return a list. So you can write something like

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM testata WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM testata)")
fun selectLast(): List<Testata>
```

And in your repo you can write

```
@WorkerThread
suspend fun lastTestata(): Testata {
    return testataDAO.selectLast().get(0)
}
```

Comment: why not just change the return type to be one item instead of a list ?